# Russian folk song sung in the movie Russkies?

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics, soundtrack, folk

Approximately 30 minutes into the 1987 film "Russkies" the main character, Mischa, sings what I assume to be a Russian folk song.  A clip is available on YouTube at [this link](https://youtu.be/CbRhfwSw9z8?t=1901).  Can you name that tune or provide a lyrics translation to English that can be googled?

Comment: If this forum doesn't get the answer for you, you may want to consider posting in [russian.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a fast answer by posting to the Russian Language Stack Exchange as suggested by Angst. The Romanized name of the song is "Shalandy polnye kefali" ("Scows Full of Mullet") by Mark Bernes. The original is available on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/hDSxfoHWCS8). The translated lyrics are available [here](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/shalandy-polnye-kefali-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-scows-full-mullet.html).